# selected indexes of same value get first item not specified index

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have three jcomboboxes that all have the respected data in them, invoice id, invoice date and invoice amount. all three have action listeners on them that sends them to a class. in the class I run a switch case to see which combobox changed. from there I get that selected item and set the other two to that selected item. e.g.

```
index = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex(); 
jComboBox3.setSelectedIndex(index);
jComboBox4.setSelectedIndex(index);
```

The problem I'm having is if the amounts are the same it selects the first index with that amount. how do I fix this?

Comment: What is an amount?

Comment: @matt amount is the amount of the invoice, its a double.

Comment: You're going to need some more code. `...from there I get that selected item and set the other two to that selected item.` That is different than the code you have posted. Did you override equals? Why should the amount matter at all? What are your combo boxes? Eg. `JComboBox<Invoice>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JComboBox internally uses `setSelectedItem` even when you call `setSelectedIndex`. The first item that `equals` is selected.

You can use a object wrapper for your amount field (I guess it is a double) that should take care of this.

Comment: I understand and agree with the reasoning as to why its happening, that makes sense and thank you for that, really appreciated, however your solution does not seem to be working as when data is loaded into a JComboBox its automatically converted into an object type, so no matter what the object wrapper, it keeps getting converted into an object?

Comment: @matt checked with jdk6. It gets the item from model and calls setselecteditem.

Comment: @Captain create a class to hold the amount, override toString.

Comment: KDM, you are correct. I was reading grepcode missed the setSelectedItem(...).

Answer (score 0):

This would be my interpretation of KDM's suggestion.

```
JComboBox<Object> idBox = new JComboBox<>();
```

Then when adding the objects:

```
idBox.add(new Object(){ public String toString(){ return invoice.id + "";}});
```

I think a better solution would be to use a custom renderer and have JComboBox, so that your invoices are stored in each box and just rendered differently, ie return the appropriate string.